# Getting text data and spliting it into 2 separate 1D arrays in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, input

I am working on a project and I am completely stuck. I basically need to read in text data from a file that is formatted like so:

4 numbers per line separated by a comma (there is no hard set of how many rows, this program should be able to work on any number of rows)

```
2, 32, 4, 7
4, 8, 3, 8
33, 11, 56, 65
```

Basically all I need are the 0 elements and the 3rd(last) elements within this text document and I need to convert them into ints and place them into their own arrays:

so for the 0 elements I would have an array (if using the above text example):

```
zeroArray[] = 2, 4, 33
thirdArray[] = 7, 8, 65
```

So, if i said `zeroArray[1]` it would be `4`, if i said `thirdArray[0]` it would say `7` (*This is using the above example data, it needs to be able to work with any number)

I need this data to be converted to `int` and in their own arrays so that I can do calculations to each element later on. I need to be able to call methods (that I will write) that will perform these calculations.

This is the problem I am having with this.

1. I cannot pull the `intArray` out of the while loop because it is declared within the while loop and that is its scope. But if I try and declare the `intArray` out of the while loop, it gives me the error 'use of unassigned local variable `intArray`. When I declare it within the while loop, and attempt to use `intArray` outside of the while loop, it gives me the error `the name intArray does not exist in the current context`. So my main problem is that I need to be able to access `intArray` so that I can use it as a parameter for my methods to perform calculations on it.
2. My second problem is `intArray` basically holds all 4 lines of data. If I print `intArray[0]`, it prints out all of the 1st numbers listed, (*using the example text from above*) it prints:

   2
   4
   33

If i print intArray[3], it prints out all of the 4th integers within the text data like so:

```
7
8
65
```

I'm assuming what I need to do is make two more arrays, one to hold the 1st elements of text, and a second to hold the 4th elements of text, because these need to be processed differently.

I have attempted to make arrays to store this data but no matter what I try, it doesn't work.
Instead of `zeroArray[0] = 2`, when I print it, it gives me the whole list:

```
2
4
33
```

If I then print `zeroArray[1]`, expecting `4`, it once again prints out the whole list

```
2
4
33
```

Unfortunately I can only use loops and 1D arrays. I cannot use lists, OOP, or 2D arrays. So the coding isn't as efficient if I could use lists/2D arrays.

I currently store the values into the int array `intArray` because I wasn't sure how to create a for loop that would be able to store the different values into two different arrays. I can't really think of a way to do so. Any method I have attempted has failed.

Can I use two arrays instead of a List? `intArray` does hold the converted integer values (4 different sections and I only need 2 of them for calculations). Is there anyway to create two arrays that hold `intArray[0]` and `intArray[3]` values so that I can proceed to do calculations with them? Also how can I make it so I can use these two arrays outside the loop? If i create an array outside the loop, it won't let me use it within the loop, and if I create an array inside the loop, it won't let me use it outside of the loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

The code attached is what is currently working. Since I can't figure out how to get the two arrays to store properly, they are not yet included in my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    //declarations
    string inputString = "";
    string[] results;
    int holder = 0;

    //import file for reading
    FileStream inFile = new FileStream("input.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader myStream = new StreamReader(inFile);

    //reads first line
    inputString = myStream.ReadLine();


    while (inputString != null)
    {
        //split the line
        results = inputString.Split(',');
        int[] intArray = new int[results.Length];


        //do whatever processing you need to do to store it


        for (int index = 0; index < results.Length; index++)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(results[index], out holder))
            {
                intArray[index] = holder;
            }//end if
        }//end for

    //reads next line
    inputString = myStream.ReadLine();



    }//end while

    //This is a test to see if the ints are correctly stored
    Console.WriteLine(intArray[0]);  //<--error here stating that 'The name intArray' does not exist in the current context'

}//end main
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use List instead of array beacuse you don't know how many lines your file has, you can easily get arrays from lists if you want by using `ToArray()` method of the list. **EDIT:Since you have stated in the comments that you need arrays, the code is adjusted for that use.** If each line has four numbers than this code might work for you. I warn you that I never check if there are less than four numbers in a row:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
        {

            //declarations
        string inputString = "";
        string[] results;
        int holder = 0;
        int []zeroArray = new int[100];
        int []thirdArray = new int[100];

        //import file for reading
        FileStream inFile = new FileStream("input.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader myStream = new StreamReader(inFile);

        //reads first line
        inputString = myStream.ReadLine();
        int count = 0;
        while (inputString != null)
        {
            //split the line
            results = inputString.Split(new char [] {','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (int.TryParse(results[0].Trim(), out holder))
            {
                zeroArray[count] = holder;
            }
            if (int.TryParse(results[3].Trim(), out holder))
            {
                thirdArray[count] = holder;
            }
            count++;
            if(count == zeroArray.Length)
            {
                int capacity = zeroArray.Length;
                int []oldArray = zeroArray;
                zeroArray = new int[2*capacity];
                oldArray.CopyTo(zeroArray,0);
                oldArray = thirdArray;
                thirdArray = new int[2*capacity];
                oldArray.CopyTo(thirdArray,0);
            }
            //reads next line
            inputString = myStream.ReadLine();
        }//end while


     }//end main
```

Note that you must regularly check the capacity of your arrays is not exceeded and if it is, you should make new instances with double the previous capacity and copy old ones to the new instances. Also, when you finish, `count` will hold the number of your numbers in each array.

Comment: "Unfortunately I can only use loops and 1D arrays. I cannot use lists, " Lists are out per requirements.

Comment: @nekizalb Check the code now, I have rewrited it to use arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Run through the file once and count the lines. Then you can declare your arrays and read the data by running a second time.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    //declarations
    string inputString = "";
    string[] results;
    int holder = 0;
    int lines = 0;

    //import file for reading
    FileStream inFile = new FileStream("input.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader myStream = new StreamReader(inFile);

    //reads first line
    inputString = myStream.ReadLine();

    while(inputString != null){
        lines++;
    }

    int[] zeroArray = new int[lines], thirdArray = new int[lines];

    FileStream inFile = new FileStream("input.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader myStream = new StreamReader(inFile);

    //reads first line
    inputString = myStream.ReadLine();

    for(int line = 0 ; line < ilnes; line++)
    {
        //split the line
        results = inputString.Split(',');
        zeroArray[line] = int.Parse(results[0]);
        thirdArray[line] = int.Parse(results[3]);

        inputString = myStream.ReadLine();
    }//end for

    //zeroArray and thirdArray should have your info now

}//end main
```

The only other option I can think of to avoid reading the file twice is to manually resize `zeroArray` and `thirdArray` as needed, since you own't know how big to make them to begin with. This is how things like `List<int>` work internally.

```
//need to resize
int[] newArray = new int[oldArray.Length *2];
for(int i=0; i<oldArray.Length; i++){
    newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
}
oldArray = newArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

are you linqed? would be so easy

```
 var splitted = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("input.txt")
       .Select(i => i.Split(',')).ToArray();
 var zeroArray = splitted.Select(s => s[0]).ToArray();
 var thirdArray = splitted.Select(s => s[3]).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

this what i try and worked perfectly. Hope it help you. Happy sharing knowledge

```
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\test.txt"))
    {
        int[] ZeroArray = null;
        int[] ThirdArray = null;

        int[] ZeroArrayTemp = null;
        int[] ThirdArrayTemp = null;

        int[] tempZero = null;
        int[] tempThird = null;

        int i = 0;

        do
        {
            i++;
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] values = line.Split(',');

            //get value for ZeroArray
            int valueZero = int.Parse(values[0]);

            //get value for ThirdArray
            int valueThird = int.Parse(values[2]);

            ZeroArrayTemp = new int[i + 1];
            ThirdArrayTemp = new int[i + 1];

            if (tempZero != null)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < tempZero.Length - 1; j++)
                {
                    ZeroArrayTemp[j] = tempZero[j];
                }
            }

            if (tempThird != null)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < tempThird.Length - 1; j++)
                {
                    ThirdArrayTemp[j] = tempThird[j];
                }
            }

            ZeroArrayTemp.SetValue(valueZero, i - 1);
            ThirdArrayTemp.SetValue(valueThird, i - 1);

            tempZero = ZeroArrayTemp;
            tempThird = ThirdArrayTemp;

        }while(sr.Peek() != -1);

        //Copy valid value to final array
        ZeroArray = new int[ZeroArrayTemp.Length - 1];
        Array.Copy(ZeroArrayTemp, ZeroArray, ZeroArrayTemp.Length - 1);

        ThirdArray = new int[ThirdArrayTemp.Length - 1];
        Array.Copy(ThirdArrayTemp, ThirdArray, ThirdArrayTemp.Length - 1);

    }
```